# Laravel Unique Validation wherein clause

Tags: validation, laravel

This is my query, that I use to do a validation

```
$hashcheck = MyTable::where('hashcode', $input['hashcode'])
->whereIn('status',['created', 'dispatched', 'viewed'])
->get();
```

I can put this as a validation

```
'hashcode'=> 'unique:my_table,hashcode,NULL,NULL,status,dispatched',
```

This generates sql like following for validation

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `invoice_details` where `invd_hashcode` = ? and `invd_status` = ?
```

So, this works for only one value of status `dispatched` but I am not able to do a wherein kind of a clause. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is currently impossible using standard Laravel rules. But you can define your own validation rule and do database query there: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules

Validation rule is defined like this:

```
Validator::extend('foo', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return $value == 'foo';
        });
```

where `foo` is the name of the validation rule.

> Defining custom validation rule might make sense if I reuse this
>   validation in more than one place

I disagree. Application validation logic should have the same structure all over your code for the sake of understandability of your application. It should not be spread over your code, sometimes being Laravel validation rule, sometimes simple comparisons and sometimes database calls.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10307034)

Comment: @user3071284 Since this is an official documentation, I think this link is a legitimate answer. Or not?

Comment: The link is probably good, but how to define a validation rule should be included inline here in the answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: Defining custom validation rule might make sense if I reuse this validation in more than one place. looks like I will do with using the query for this time. I am not sure if this can be excepted as answer, but it clearly answers my question, "Is there a way to do this?" Answer: No. Any suggestions welcome

Comment: @karmedra I've improved my answer, guys.

Comment: @user3071284 Added an example from documentation into my answer. Thanks ;)